# Thymeleaf : create URL with parameters

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I have this function in a Thymeleaf template to create the URL

```
/company/delete/id
```

with this function

```
function confirmDelete (id) {
        var r = confirm("Are you sure to delete the item #" + id + " ?");
        if (r == true) {
            var link = /*[[@{/company/delete/}]]*/ + id;
            window.location.href = link;
        } 
}
```

but the id is ignored and the URL generated is `/company/delete/`  without the id

Comment: uhh it's partially commented out isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you comment out your Thymeleaf/javascript like that, Thymeleaf is attempting to make [JavaScript natural templates work](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-natural-templates).  It deletes everything after the end of the comment because it thinks you are trying to make the template work both using Thymeleaf to process, and just viewing it in your browser without processing.

You should just move where you are appending the id.

```
function confirmDelete (id) {
  var r = confirm("Are you sure to delete the item #" + id + " ?");
  if (r == true) {
    var link = /*[[@{/company/delete/}]]*/ "";
    window.location.href = link + id;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript, you have to add th:inline="javascript" to your enclosing  tag. I had to add this to make it work, too:

```html
<script th:inline="javascript">
                /*<![CDATA[*/
                url: /*[('"' + @{/api/project/search/findProjectsForUser} + '"')]*/ "/api/project/search/findProjectsForUser",
                /*]]>*/
</script>
```